# Authentication with phone number on firebase error : 'Unable to load external reCAPTCHA dependencies!'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I implemented the authentication with phone number for my mobile application with firebase.

([Link of the tutorial](https://enappd.com/blog/firebase-phone-authentication-in-ionic-5-apps/169/))

It works pretty well on a desktop (even tho it is asking me for the capcha even if I'm using the invisible version), but on mobile phone, I have the following error :
`{"code":"auth/internal-error","message":"Unable to load external reCAPTCHA dependencies!"}`

Any Idea where that problem come from and if anyone knows how to implement the sms authentication please ?

Comment: Did your issue resolved ? I am also facing same error with Phone auth with Firebase iOS SDK .  @frank-van-puffelen

Comment: no solution Yet. I'm using emailing connexion for the moment, but it is a real pain point to me

Comment: any updates about this issue @SurjeetSingh because I am facing this issue –

Comment: any updates about this issue @Aion because I am facing this issue

Comment: This problem with some others limitations i had made me switch technologies. This problem was never resolved on my side unfortunatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using firebase phone auth in flutter application and was facing same issue.

I was able to solve by enabling Android Device Verification api in GCP.

Select your project and enable Android Device Verification.
[GCP API link](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable [Google Play Integrity API](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/playintegrity.googleapis.com) even for iOS.